# R: Round to varying thresholds

Tags: r

I have a vector of numbers that I need to round according to the rules in the image below:

[image]

Consider the following examples:

```
0.5 -> 0.5 (no rounding)
1.2 -> 1.0
3.7 -> 4.0
18.9 -> 20.0
28.1 -> 30.0
110 -> 120
```

I could in theory write a series of conditional statements to achieve this task; however, it will be a tedious and inefficient thing to do. Is there a way to achieve the desired outcome in an efficient manner?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `floor` of base 10 logarithm to calculate powers of 10. Then divide the vector by that, round it and multiply with the powers of 10 again.

```
tens <- 10^floor(log10(abs(x)))
round(x/tens)*tens
# [1]   NaN   0.5   1.0   4.0  -4.0  20.0  30.0 100.0
```

*Note*, that this won't work for zero and you therefore should use case-handling.

(However, 110 -> 120 is not obvious to me.)

---

*Data:*

```
x <- c(0, .5, 1.2, 3.7, -3.7, 18.9, 28.1, 110)
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses `findInterval` to get which of the rounding functions is to be applied to the vector's elements.

```
roundSpecial <- function(x){
  round_funs <- list(
    no_round <- function(x) x,
    round_by_1 <- function(x) round(x),
    round_to_20 <- function(x) 20,
    round_by_10 <- function(x) 10*round(x / 10),
    round_by_15 <- function(x) 15*round(x / 15),
    round_by_30 <- function(x) 30*round(x / 30)
  )
  lims <- c(0, 1, 17, 20, 30, 90, Inf)
  which_fun <- findInterval(x, lims)
  sapply(seq_along(which_fun), function(i) {
    round_funs[[ which_fun[i] ]](x[i])
  })
}

roundSpecial(x)
#[1]   0.5   1.0   4.0  20.0  30.0 120.0
```

**Data**

```
x <- c(0.5, 1.2, 3.7, 18.9, 28.1, 110)
```